# Swift: how to update boolean value parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, boolean, updating

i dont have that much experience so please be friendly while explaining

i can't update my boolean value through swift.

```
 let parseQuery = PFQuery(className: "request")        
    parseQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
        for object in objects {

        object.setValue(false, forKey: "isRead") //tried this and didn't work
        object["isRead"] = false //tried this and didn't work as well..

            }
      }
}
```

the method i use to update my boolean is wrong?

Comment: What's the type of the `object` in your for-loop?

Comment: Try this ``object["isRead"] = NSNumber(bool: false)`` or ``object.setValue(NSNumber(bool: false), forKey: "isRead")``

Comment: Parse is now longer working so you should find another backend service

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Did it not update the object in the backend? Did it not compile? Did it throw an error at runtime? Did it create a worm hole to a dimension where you never asked this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to saveEventually()

```
object["isRead"] = NSNumber(bool: false)
object.saveEventually()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the ACL of your object. When saving objects to Parse, write something like this

```
object.ACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true)
```

For the existing objects, go into your class and scroll to the right to the ACL. Then set the public write access to true. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but its wasnt from ACL it was my fault for not saving the objects

Comment: Ok. Glad you found the solution. I will leave the solution up in case anybody else comes across this.

Answer (score 0):

You never saved your objects after updating them.